# Panel not appearing on clicking button

Tags: java, swing, radio-button

I am using group radio buttons.What i want is that when i have selected the particular radio button then i press the button(call it show button) to display the results(on a chart placed in a panel) according to the selected radio button.The problem is when i press the show button it does not display results until i click the panel though i have not written any code when i press the panel.Here is my code

```
private void Show1MouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {
    if (jRadioButton1.isSelected()) {
        Panel.removeAll();
       //some code
    }

    Panel.setVisible(true);
    Panel.add(frame1);
    Panel.setSize(700, 260);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably need to call `repaint()` on your panel after the change. When you interact with the panel with your mouse it is calling `repaint()` behind the scenes.

Answer (score 3):

Use a [CardLayout](http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/CardLayout.html), as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5665156/calling-awt-frame-methods-from-subclass/5786005#5786005).

[image: Game view]  [image: High Scores view]

As to the chart itself, change the model if the data changes.